# 'no instance' error when importing custom module in ghci

Tags: haskell, import, ghci

I am trying to import a custom module into main using ghci and I am getting this error I don't really understand.

Main.hs

```
module Main where

import Newton (my_sqrt)

main = my_sqrt 25
```

Newton.hs

```
module Newton where

deriv f x = (f(x + dx) - f(x))/dx
    where dx = 0.0001


newton f = until satis improve
    where   satis y = abs(f y) < eps
            eps = 0.0001
            improve y = y - (f y/deriv f y)


my_sqrt x = newton f x
    where f y = y^2 - x

my_cubrt x = newton f x
    where f y = y**3 - x
```

I try to load these into ghci using

```
:l Main.hs
```

I get this error

```
Main.hs:9:8: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional (IO t0))
        arising from a use of ‘my_sqrt’
    • In the expression: my_sqrt 25
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = my_sqrt 25

Main.hs:9:16: error:
    • No instance for (Num (IO t0)) arising from the literal ‘25’
    • In the first argument of ‘my_sqrt’, namely ‘25’
      In the expression: my_sqrt 25
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = my_sqrt 25
Failed, modules loaded: Newton.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The type of `main` is required to be `IO ()`.

The type of `sqrt 25` is, apparently, `Fractional t => t` (it is really advisable to always include type signatures for your top-level entities in the program; you miss those).

To reconcile the two you can define e.g.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (sqrt 25)
```

because the type of `print` is `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`.